# neutron-linuxbridge-agent oslo_service.service amqp.exceptions.InternalError: Connection.open: (541) INTERNAL_ERROR

Tags: rabbitmq, openstack, bridge, openstack-neutron

Openstack Train version's **neutron-linuxbridge-agent** component's log show error:

```
2022-03-17 14:38:36.727 6 ERROR oslo_service.service   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 648, in _on_close
2022-03-17 14:38:36.727 6 ERROR oslo_service.service     (class_id, method_id), ConnectionError)
2022-03-17 14:38:36.727 6 ERROR oslo_service.service amqp.exceptions.InternalError: Connection.open: (541) INTERNAL_ERROR - access to vhost '/' refused for user 'openstack': vhost '/' is down
2022-03-17 14:38:36.727 6 ERROR oslo_service.service 
2022-03-17 14:38:36.729 6 INFO neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent [-] Stopping Linux bridge agent agent.
```

`docker logs neutron_linuxbridge_agent` get:

```
++ /usr/bin/update-alternatives --query iptables
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for iptables
++ . /usr/local/bin/kolla_neutron_extend_start
+ echo 'Running command: '\''neutron-linuxbridge-agent --config-file /etc/neutron/neutron.conf --config-file /etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/ml2_conf.ini'\'''
+ exec neutron-linuxbridge-agent --config-file /etc/neutron/neutron.conf --config-file /etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/ml2_conf.ini
Running command: 'neutron-linuxbridge-agent --config-file /etc/neutron/neutron.conf --config-file /etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/ml2_conf.ini'
```

All `openstack network agent list` show state are **UP**, but Alive are **XXX**.

What's the problem with my cluster, and how could I fixed that? Thanks a lot.

The key server is **rabbitmq** reference of `amqp.exceptions.InternalError`, and the **rabbit@node-3.log** shows:

```
2022-03-18 06:50:35.270 [error] <0.21119.0> Error on AMQP connection <0.21119.0> (1.1.1.2:12345 -> 1.1.1.3:55672 - neutron-linuxbridge-agent:7:11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111, vhost: 'none', user: 'openstack', state: opening), channel 0:
 {handshake_error,opening,
                 {amqp_error,internal_error,
                             "access to vhost '/' refused for user 'openstack': vhost '/' is down",
                             'connection.open'}}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you wanna fix your problem easily please deploy your Rabbimq again with Kolla-ansible.

```
kolla-ansible -i <INVENTORY> deploy -t rabbitmq -vvvv
```

it's my experience that the easiest way with the lowest cost of fixing Rabbimq or oslo problem in OpenStack is to redeploy Rabbitmq and invest your time.

Comment: it's also a good method, thanks bro.

Comment: Good answer! In case of remaining errors, make sure there is not any important pending message there, then you can delete all the files related to RabbitMQ (e.g. files in 'RABBITMQ_MNESIA_DIR' or in its docker volume) and then use your mentioned command.

Answer (score 1):

While check and login the `rabbitmq` server site(http://1.1.1.3:15672/), I get this error tip:

```
rabbitmq virtual host experienced an error on node and may be inaccessible
```

Solve it by:

- 1, come in the `rabbitmq` container, and remove or move out **recovery.dets** file in directory **/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@node-3/msg_stores/vhosts/628WB79CIFDYO9LJI6DKMI09L**.
- 2, restart `rabbitmq` container.

Because of:

> In RabbitMQ versions starting with 3.7.0 all messages data is combined in the msg_stores/vhosts directory and stored in a subdirectory per vhost. Each vhost directory is named with a hash and contains a .vhost file with the vhost name, so a specific vhost's message set can be backed up separately.

> In RabbitMQ versions prior to 3.7.0 messages are stored in several directories under the node data directory: queues, msg_store_persistent and msg_store_transient. Also there is a recovery.dets file which contains recovery metadata if the node was stopped gracefully.

My whole cluster was reboot by accident, it was recoveried by this method.